# What is the "async desaster" Detlef Vollmann was talking about at Meeting C++ 2014?

Tags: c++, async

I found the slides of his talk there: https://meetingcpp.com/tl_files/2014/talks/executors-meetingcpp.pdf

In one of the last pages, he is talking about the "async desaster" (which I, as a non-native speaker, read as "async disaster"). What disaster was he referring to exactly?

Comment: I would have said the same, but there's no reference to 'disaster' either elsewhere in his talk so I'm not sure. Mind you, the conference has "platin sponsors" so I think the whole thing is non-native English!

Comment: Indeed. I have no doubt he was meaning "disaster". I wonder about the technical details.

Comment: Note that in that slide, `async` is written in the code font. He's referring specifically to the `async` function, which was a hastily added high-level threading facility added to C++11, basically just so there would be one, which has poorly specified semantics and thus isn't that useful for real-world programs in my experience. He's probably referring to that.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I hadn't thought of this one. I thought he was talking about the C# thing. But what you say makes more sense.